# How can I avoid anonymous / inline functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I am relative new to JS / JQuery / HTML and am looking for a way to avoid using so many inline / anonymous functions.

here is the example of what I have working:

```
initialize: function () {
    $('section.content').each(this.initWaypoints);
}

initWaypoints: function (index, item) {

    $(item).waypoint(function (direction) {
        $('.navButton.' + $(item).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');

    },{offset: '50%',vertical: true})

    $(item).waypoint(function (direction) {
        $('.navButton.' + $(item).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');

    },{offset: '-50%', vertical: true});

}
```

What i would prefer is something like this:

```
initialize: function () {
    $('section.content').each(this.initWaypoints);
},

initWaypoints: function (index, item) {
    $(item).waypoint(this.down, {offset: '50%', vertical: true});              
    $(item).waypoint(this.up, {offset: '-50%', vertical: true});
},

down: function (direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + $(item).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
},

up: function (direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + $(item).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');
}
```

My problem is that my up and down methods do not know what $(item) is because they are not the same scope as the first example. And i have not found out how to pass item to them.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's why you use the anonymous functions. They'll have the proper scoping.

Comment: Do you use `up` and `down` elsewhere?

Comment: just pass the `$(item)` or whatever as a parameter

Comment: @akonsu I don't believe he can with the current way he's calling `up` and `down`.

Comment: he cannot. he would need to implement partial application. which would take him back to anonymous functions.

Comment: @akonsu - These days, JavaScript has `Function.bind`, so partial application can be done without (explicit) anonymous functions.

Comment: @TedHopp yeah... thanks. it was useful to learn about `bind`. which is the way to go in this case I suppose.

Comment: Try `$(this)` since your functions are callbacks on `$(item)` (depends on the `waypoint` plugin whether that works)

Comment: do you mean

$(item).waypoint($(this).down, {offset: '50%', vertical: true});
        $(item).waypoint($(this).up, {offset: '-50%', vertical: true});

Answer (score 2):

There are probably several approaches to do what you want. One is to provide an extra `item` argument to your functions and bind the argument when you pass the functions to `waypoint`:

```
initWaypoints: function (index, item) {
    $(item).waypoint(this.down.bind(this, $(item)), {offset: '50%', vertical: true});              
    $(item).waypoint(this.up.bind(this, $(item)), {offset: '-50%', vertical: true});
},

down: function (item, direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + item.data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
},

up: function (item, direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + item.data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for all the answers. Teds solution does exactly what I wanted. I wanted to avoid the anonymous functions is I find the syntax to be really difficult to read and thought there must be a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use closures.

Try this:

```
initialize: function () {
    $('section.content').each(this.initWaypoints);
},

initWaypoints: function (index, item) {
    $(item).waypoint(this.down(item), {offset: '50%', vertical: true});              
    $(item).waypoint(this.up(item), {offset: '-50%', vertical: true});
},

down: function (item) {
    return function(direction) {
      $('.navButton.' + $(item).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
  }
},

up: function (item) {
   return function(direction) {
      $('.navButton.' + item.data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');
   }
}
```

Comment: This also works but could you explain what exactly the 

     return function(direction) {

     }

part is doing

Comment: Now that I thought about it I understand.  You are returning the function.

Comment: `Funtion.bind` is right one solution, but If you are concerned about its browser support. This is one of your way out.

Comment: Thanks for the help both ways improve the readability and portability a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about building elaborate object model and just want to sling together some jQuery then you can simply use `this`:

```
down: function (direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + $(this).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'down');
},

up: function (direction) {
    $('.navButton.' + $(this).data('label')).toggleClass('active', direction === 'up');
}
```

Comment: But would this not refer to the class that puts everything together and not the item that is triggering the waypoint?

Comment: @GregoryJacob no. What you have is conceptually equivalent to `HashMap<String, Function>`, not a class... Secondly, `this` reference is resolved for each call separately, it has no relation to where a function is defined.